# Append new operations to an existing API with Az Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In Azure API Management, I'm looking at the possibility of appending new operations to an existing API revision.

I can do it in Azure portal like below.
[image]

I don't see this flexibility (choosing between update and append) available in the powershell command that imports API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/import-azapimanagementapi?view=azps-4.7.0

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/new-azapimanagementoperation?view=azps-4.7.0) to implement it.

```
$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "Api-Default-WestUS" -ServiceName "contoso"
New-AzApiManagementOperation -Context $apimContext -ApiId $APIId -OperationId "Operation001" -Name "Operation" -Method "GET" -UrlTemplate "/resource" -Description "Use this operation to get resource"
```

Comment: I'm looking at appending new operations by providing a Spec file, as per the screenshot I provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the PowerShell cmdlet `Import-AzApiManagementApi` as documented here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/import-azapimanagementapi?view=azps-5.7.0